# View not updating content text after action execution

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I'm passing string data using ajax to MVC controller named StockData:

...

```
mypostrequest.open("POST", "/home/stockData", true)
mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
mypostrequest.send(json)
```

MVC Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult StockData(StockData model)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            using (EFDbContext db = new EFDbContext())
            {
                    foreach (var item in model.Items)
                    {
                        var company = db.Company.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == item.Code);
                        if (company != null)
                        {
                            db.Stock.Add(new Stock()
                                {
                                    Date = model.PublicationDate,
                                    CompanyID = company.CompanyID,
                                    Company = company,
                                    Price = item.Price
                                });
                        }
                    }
                    this.TerminateStock(db);
            }
            return PartialView(model);
        }

@using StockExchange.WebUI.Models
@model StockData
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Stocks";
}


<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
             <td>@Model.PublicationDate</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I not understand what I'm doing wrong. While debugging above code, data is successfuly filled with correct data, but after execution of action StockData nothing changes (data is correctly passed to View). I'm grateful for your help

Comment: Where do you actually respond to the AJAX request and update the page?

Comment: I hadn't any respond code..
  mypostrequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                         if (mypostrequest.status == 200) {
                                 document.getElementById("partialResult").innerHTML = mypostrequest.responseText;
                             }
 Thank you for attention I resolved my issue.